# /usr/bin/ld: -f may not be used without -shared

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, build

i was trying to build the executable binary of an opengl app from this repo [Cherno OpenGL Tutorial](https://github.com/rajsahae/thecherno_opengl/tree/linux/ep23-rendering-multiple-objects) .
But when i run make command the get the following error how to resolve it

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui -I/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui/../external  -I/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui/vendor/imgui  -I/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui/vendor/stb_image -DDEBUG -g -c -o vendor/stb_image/stb_image.o vendor/stb_image/stb_image.cpp
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui -I/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui/../external  -I/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui/vendor/imgui  -I/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui/vendor/stb_image -DDEBUG -g -L/home/john/Music/fastapi/thecherno_opengl/ep22-imgui/../lib -lglfw3 -lGLEW -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -o app  Application.o  IndexBuffer.o  Renderer.o  Shader.o  Texture.o  VertexArray.o  VertexBuffer.o  vendor/imgui/imgui.o  vendor/imgui/imgui_demo.o  vendor/imgui/imgui_draw.o  vendor/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw_gl3.o  vendor/stb_image/stb_image.o

/usr/bin/ld: -f may not be used without -shared
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:29: app] Error 1
```

t tried different options like -f and -shared but not able to resolve the problem

Comment: `-framework` is Apple Clang key. You are on Linux. Remove all of `-framework` with the following names.

Comment: Please read the instructions on how to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).